# Is it possible to use fortran function as its own argument?

Tags: python, fortran

I wanted to find value of a certain function which is recursive in nature. For example, consider the function defined as follows:

```
 A(m,n) = n+1 if m=0
        = A(m-1,A(m-1,n)) if m is not 0
```

In python I can write this function easily:

```
def A(m,n):
    if(m==0):
        return n+1
    else:
        return A(m-1,A(m-1,n))
```

But I am not able to write a similar function in FORTRAN. The basic reason is that FORTRAN functions do not allow themselves to be their own arguments. Is there any way to get over this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Fortran version are you using? I know that in (at least) Fortran 90 recursion is possible. This post is an example of Fortran recursion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816351/fortran-functions

Comment: Note that in your example code `A` is not an argument of `A`.  `A` takes arguments `m` and `n` neither of which shows any signs of being itself a function; rather they look as if they might be integers.  `A` calls itself, it is recursive, but that is not the same thing at all as a function which can handle itself as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a working solution for your problem, if your compiler supports fortran 90.

```
  program recursivetest
  implicit none
  integer A,n,m

  n=2
  m=2
  print*, A(m,n)
  end

  recursive function A(m,n) result (B)
  implicit none

  integer n,m,B,C

  if (m.ne.0) then
          C=A(m-1,n)
          B=A(m-1,C)
  else
          B=n+1
  endif

  end function
```

I compiled this code using ifort (intel fortran composer 2011 sp. 1) and gfortran. Intel fortran compiler will also allow this kind of definition for recursive functions:

```
  recursive integer function A(m,n)
```

or:

```
  integer recursive function A(m,n)
```

Strict FORTRAN 77 standard does not directly support recursive functions, although there are ways to solve this problem. If you use FORTRAN 77, please tell us about it. I can't test it right now and i'm not sure how it works anymore.

Comment: Your example number 2 doesn't resolve anything. Recursion is still a recursion, even if it is not direct.

Comment: You might be right. I messed up the part with FORTRAN 77. I take it out.