# Calculate differential in Fortran

Tags: math, fortran, mathematical-optimization, fortran90, fortran95

I want to calculate `w` for `j=0 to n` in the below function. Is there any already written library for this in FORTRAN?

[image]

Actually I want to write a program that get `n` from the user, and print `w` in output. What shall I do for differential and for creating the equation `Ln(x)`?

Comment: I suspect there's no Fortran library which solve this specific problem.  Are you looking for an algebraic solution or a numerical one?  What have you tried so far?  And do you mean a "difference equation" as opposed to a "differential"?

Comment: Also, what is the point of q(x)?  Is that just an artifact from the image you're linking or is there some significance which makes it relevant to this question?

Comment: have a look at this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816351/fortran-functions   then make an attempt at writing some code..

Comment: (1) If `L` is a Lagrange or Laguerre polynomial or some other well-known family, there are probably a lot of identities that can help you find exact, symbolic solutions. Maybe take a look at Abramowitz & Stegun "Handbook of Mathematical Functions" (pretty sure it's on the web) or a similar book. (2) `x_j` is defined as a root of `L[n + 1]` but then in the definition of `w_j` there is a division by `L[n + 1](x_j)` which must be zero, right? Something fishy there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That recurrence relation will generate the n-th order Legendre polynomial, and from the x<sub>j</sub> and w<sub>j</sub>, I assume you are writing a program to perform Gauss-Legendre integration (no idea why the q(x) is there).

This [Florida State page](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/legendre_rule/legendre_rule.html) provides an [LGPL Fortran90 program](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/legendre_rule/legendre_rule.f90) that calculates the nodes and weights using a tridiagonal-eigenvalue method and writing them to an external file.  You could try and collect all of the contained functions and place them into a module for run-time calculation of the nodes and weights.

Comment: good call, note it should be `L-prime` in the weight formula, which explains the anomaly noted by robert.